# TreeView nodes behaving strangely

Tags: wpf, xaml, binding, treeview

In  the `TreeView` below, why **Layer1** node doesn't show the icon like **Layer3** does, even though Snoop tells me the icon is there? (only the right-most part is my app; the left two portions is Snoop)

[image]

A few things I noted in Snoop (word "highlighted" refers to the red arrowheads):

1. `ContentPresenter.Content` of **Layer1** is set correctly (highlighted: center-top), but it doesn't show the Image node under it, unlike the Layer3 node (highlighted: left-bottom).
2. I compared the `ContentPresenter`s of the two nodes, and they have identical proeprty values except for `DesiredSize`, which is set to 0,0 for Layer 1 (highlighted: center-bottom). Don't know why is this so.
3. I tried added more Layer nodes under FRONT. The icon shows only for the bottom-most node; all other layer nodes appear without icon.

I'm using [MultiSelectTreeView](https://github.com/dg9ngf/MultiSelectTreeView) here if that has something to do. Root node, FRONT and BACK nodes are added statically through XAML, while the child nodes are populated through binding.

Comment: I downloaded the MultiSelectTreeView project from GitHut and its demo seems to work correcty... I guess it is something related to your code. Can you show us the most relevant parts of your code, please?

Comment: Just for giggles, what do you have the build action set to for the icon files?

Comment: @ChrisW.: If that were the problem, it wouldn't be showing anywhere. See that it is showing for Layer3 node.

Comment: I see one as embedded in the ContentPresenter of Item, but not on the other according to your snoop tree which is why I asked, might want to share how you're placing it.